# UISwitch constraints and animation break on tableview.reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

So I am trying to change a bool value using a UISwitch in my project.  The switch is positioned on the right of my cell, and is held in place with constraints added via Interface Builder.

I have rigged up the switch to call a `switchChanged` method which sets the bool value, and then reloads the tableView to reflect the changed value.

The switch works correctly, setting the bool value when it is toggled.  However, when the `switchChanged` method calls `self.tableView.reloadData()`, the switch is repositioned in the top left of the cell, and it no longer animates, though it still functions properly.  Something is breaking the switch, but as a novice iOS developer, I am not sure how to begin troubleshooting.

Here is the relevant code:

```
cellSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged),
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

And then:

```
func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch) -> Void {
    print("Switch changed to \(sender.on).")

    if sender.on {
        self.acknowledged = "confirmed"
    } else {
        self.acknowledged = "conflicted"
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Somehow the `tableView.reloadData()` line is breaking the switch.  Everything else works except the switch position and animation.  Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

The `switchChanged()` method is implemented in my view controller.

Here are the constraints mentioned above:

[image: These]

Comment: You'll need to show the constraints that you've added. Also, where is the `switchChanged()` method implemented? In the cell, or the view controller?

Comment: `switchChanged()` is happening in the view controller

Comment: i dont get your question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay!  I have absolutely no idea what was happening here, but I figured out how to keep the switch in place.

Instead of creating the accessory view, I am adding the target directly to the switch, and everything works as expected.  Here is the updated code:

```
customCell.acknowledgedSwitch.addTarget(self, 
    action: #selector(self.switchChanged),
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CellWithSwitchDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var switchOn = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellWithSwitch") as? CellWithSwitch {
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.switcher.on = switchOn
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}

func switchValueChanged(cell: CellWithSwitch, sender: UISwitch) {
    print("Switch changed to \(sender.on).")
    switchOn = sender.on

    let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: 0)
    tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .Left)
}
}
```

> CellWithSwitch.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol CellWithSwitchDelegate {
func switchValueChanged(cell: CellWithSwitch, sender: UISwitch)
}

class CellWithSwitch: UITableViewCell {

var delegate: CellWithSwitchDelegate?
@IBOutlet var switcher: UISwitch!

@IBAction func valueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {

    if let delegate = self.delegate {
        delegate.switchValueChanged(self, sender: sender)
    }
}
}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
    <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_39104992" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kbL-PU-bnt">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="600" height="572"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <prototypes>
                                <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="CellWithSwitch" id="Xxo-pE-rjH" customClass="CellWithSwitch" customModule="stackoverflow_39104992" customModuleProvider="target">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="600" height="44"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="Xxo-pE-rjH" id="bAF-fu-1lQ">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="43"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" on="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gWn-Oz-kuT">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="543" y="6" width="51" height="31"/>
                                                <connections>
                                                    <action selector="valueChanged:" destination="Xxo-pE-rjH" eventType="valueChanged" id="clu-XE-TxT"/>
                                                </connections>
                                            </switch>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="gWn-Oz-kuT" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="bAF-fu-1lQ" secondAttribute="centerY" id="DhQ-ae-Twa"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="gWn-Oz-kuT" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="bAF-fu-1lQ" secondAttribute="trailingMargin" id="aCN-km-CK1"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </tableViewCellContentView>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                    <connections>
                                        <outlet property="switcher" destination="gWn-Oz-kuT" id="kG6-g5-aiA"/>
                                    </connections>
                                </tableViewCell>
                            </prototypes>
                        </tableView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="kbL-PU-bnt" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="3Df-X8-7Qt"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="kbL-PU-bnt" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="Tqy-17-xK7"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="kbL-PU-bnt" secondAttribute="trailing" id="iFb-Yl-HBW"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="kbL-PU-bnt" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="wfy-db-euE" secondAttribute="top" id="isL-f5-3bE"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="tableView" destination="kbL-PU-bnt" id="9kH-Gx-tmj"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="753" y="576"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Have you looked at my code? What do you think about such a realization? It seems to me more evident.